# Problem in Chromium browser logging

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, multiple-users

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04. It originally was Lubuntu 12.04, then I installed xubuntu-desktop. I'm still using Chromium as my browser because it's running on a Netbook.

Everything works really well except for one small annoyance. I have other users who use the system now and then. When I run Chromium, it works as you would expect. When any other user runs it, Chromium starts a terminal window to show output. This is confusing for some of them.

I've checked their `/home` directories and they seem identical to mine wrt Chromium (i.e. they have a `.cache` and all its subdirectories are the same as mine). The shortcuts all launch Chromium with the same command:

```
/usr/bin/X11/chromium-browser
```

At first I thought it was just because they didn't have access to `/var/log`. But now I'm not so sure. It doesn't look like Chromium logs to that directory; it must log to the user's home directory, though I haven't found the output from my session yet.

How do I get Chromium to work the same for my other users as it does for me?

Specifically, no terminal window at launch and logging to their home directories.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The issue was the 'Run in Terminal' box was checked when I created the launcher. I don't remember checking it, but must have done so by accident, because that's not the default in Xfce.

Sorry, that was really stupid.